# mergesort recursion in mips

Tags: mips, mergesort

I am working with  mergesort mips operating on Mars

i run it, the array is arranged but it has some troubles and it announces that  error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000

Go: execution terminated with errors
please help me
thank you very much

```
.data   # Data declaration section

text1:      .asciiz "My array"
text2:      .asciiz "Sorted Array"
newline:    .asciiz "\n"
space:  .asciiz "    "

Myarray:        .word  9 5 6 8 7 2 


mangx:  .word 0:20
mangy:  .word 0:20
    .text

main:


    la  $a0, Myarray        # load dia chi myarray $a1
    addi    $t1, $zero,4        # size=20 
    and $a1, $zero, $zero   # l=0 a1
    addi    $a3,$zero,3     #r=19




    li  $v0, 4          
    la  $a0, text1      #in text1
    syscall


    li  $v0, 4          
    la  $a0, newline        #in newline
    syscall

    and $t4, $zero, $zero   # khoi tao i=0 $t4
    j   LoopPrintUn     # nhay den ham in myarray

LoopPrintUn:                
        la  $a0, Myarray        # load dia chi myarray $a1
    #While (i < length) 
    slt     $t6, $t4, $t1       # neu i < size thi $t6=1, neu khong thi $t6=0
    beq $t6, $zero, call    # neu $t6=0 thi re qua ham in Sortedarray

    # Load Array[i] and print it
    sll $t0, $t4, 2     # i * 4 
    add $t6, $a0, $t0       # chuyen den dia chi phan tu thu i
    li  $v0, 1          # ham in integer
    lw  $a0, 0($t6)     # load gia tri tai dia chi thu i
    syscall                 # in 


    li  $v0, 4          
    la  $a0, space      
    syscall                     #in khoang trang

    addi    $t4, $t4, 1     # i ++
    j   LoopPrintUn     # lap ham in myarray






MergeSort:
    addi $sp, $sp, -20
     sw $ra,0($sp)
    sw $a3, 12($sp)  # r
    sw $a1, 8($sp)   # l
    sw $a0, 4($sp)   # a[]



    slt $t6, $a1, $a3   # neu l < r $t6=1 neu khong $t6=0
    beq $t6, $zero, Exit2   # $t6=0 thi exit2

    add $t1, $a1, $a3   # temp1 = l + r
    div $t1, $t1, 2     # temp1 = temp1 / 2
   add $a3,$t1,$zero
    sw  $t1,16($sp)
   # add $a3, $a2, $zero # m=(l+r)/2 (m thay cho cho r trong mergesort(arr,l,r))
    jal MergeSort       # mergesort(arr,l,m)
    lw $a1,16($sp) #load m
    addi $a1,$a1,1 
    lw $a3,12($sp)#load r





    #addi $sp, $sp, 24
    jal MergeSort       # mergesort(arr,m+1,r)  

    lw $a0, 4($sp)
    lw $a1, 8($sp)
    lw $a2, 16($sp)
    lw $a3, 12($sp)


    jal merge       # merge(a,l,m,r)






Exit2: 
lw $ra,0($sp)
lw $a0, 4($sp)
 lw $a1, 8($sp)
  lw $a2, 16($sp)
    lw $a3, 12($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 20
jr $ra
merge:
addi $sp,$sp,-32
sw $ra,0($sp)
sw $s0,4($sp) # bien i
sw $s1,8($sp) # bien j
sw $s2,12($sp) # bien k
sw $s3,16($sp) # bien n1
sw $s4,20($sp) # bien n2
sw $s5,24($sp) # mang X
sw $s6,28($sp) # mang y

la $s5,mangx
la $s6,mangy
sub $s3,$a2,$a1 # m-l
addi $s3,$s3,1 #m-l+1
sub $s4,$a3,$a2 # r-m
move $t0,$0 # bien dem o
move $t1,$0 # bien dem p
loop1:
slt $t3,$t0,$s3 # so sanh o<n1
beq $t3,$0,loop2 # go to toi loop 2 neu $t3=0
sll $t2,$t0,2 # o*4
add $t2,$s5,$t2 # X[0]
add $t5,$a1,$t0 # l+o
sll $t5,$t5,2 # (l+o)*4
add $t5,$a0,$t5 # arr[l+o]
lw $t5,0($t5)
sw $t5,0($t2) # x[o]=arr[l+o]
addi $t0,$t0,1 #o++
j loop1
loop2:
# xuly
slt $t4,$t1,$s4 # so sanh o<n1
beq $t4,$0,exit # go to toi exit neu $tt4=0
addi $t6,$a2,1 # m+1
add $t6,$t6,$t1 #m+1+p
sll $t6,$t6,2 #(m+1+p)*4
sll $t7,$t1,2 # p*4
add $t6,$a0,$t6 # arr[m+1+p]
lw $t6,0($t6)
add $t7,$s6,$t7 # y[p]
sw $t6,0($t7) # y[p]=arr[m+1+p]
addi $t1,$t1,1 #o++
j loop2
#-------------
exit:
move $s0,$0 #i=0
move $s1,$0 # j=0
add $s2,$a1,$0 #k=l  
while:
slt $t0,$s0,$s3 #i<n1
beq $t0,$0,loop3
slt $t1,$s1,$s4 #j<n2
beq $t1,$0,loop3
sll $t2,$s0,2 #i*4
sll $t3,$s1,2 #j*4
add $t2,$s5,$t2 #x[i]
lw $t2,0($t2)
add $t3,$s6,$t3 #y[j]
lw $t3,0($t3)
    slt $t6,$t2,$t3 # x[i]<y[j]
    beq $t6,$0,else #x[i] >y[j] thì làm else còn x[i] <= y[j] lam if
    sll $t7,$s2,2 #k*4
    add $t7,$a0,$t7 #arr[k]
    sw $t2,0($t7) #arr[k]=x[i]
    addi $s0,$s0,1 #i++
    addi $s2,$s2,1 #k++
    else:
    sll $t7,$s2,2 #k*4
    add $t7,$a0,$t7 #arr[k]
    sw $t3,0($t7) #arr[k]=y[j]
    addi $s1,$s1,1 #j++ 
    addi $s2,$s2,1 #k++

j while
loop3:
slt $t0,$s0,$s3 #i<n1
beq $t0,$0,loop4
sll $t1,$s2,2 #k*4
add $t1,$a0,$t1 #arr[k]
sll $t2,$s0,2 #i*4
add $t2,$s5,$t2 #x[i]
lw $t2,0($t2)
sw $t2,0($t1) #arr[k]=x[i]
addi $s0,$s0,1 #i++
addi $s2,$s2,1 #k++
j loop3
loop4:
slt $t0,$s1,$s4 #j<n2
beq $t0,$0,exit1
sll $t1,$s2,2 #k*4
add $t1,$a0,$t1 #arr[k]
sll $t2,$s1,2 #j*4
add $t2,$s6,$t2 #y[j]
lw $t2,0($t2)
sw $t2,0($t1) #arr[k]=y[j]
addi $s1,$s1,1 #j++
addi $s2,$s2,1 #k++
j loop4
exit1:
lw $ra,0($sp)
addi $sp,$sp,32
jr $ra
call:
jal MergeSort
```

Comment: Lol why are you doing this to yourself. This is either one hell of a school assignment or you love ripping your hair out.

Comment: `call: jal MergeSort` I'm not sure what you expected to happen when `MergeSort` returns, but the CPU will just keep executing whatever it finds at `PC`.

Comment: pls help me fix it